# react-mathjax renders twice. How can I fix?

Tags: reactjs, render, mathjax

I am trying to use `react-mathjax` in `reactjs`.

The following is my code.

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import MathJax from "react-mathjax";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [text, setText] = useState("");
      
      const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target.value);
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <textarea onChange={handleOnChange} />
          <MathJax.Provider>
            <MathJax.Node formula={text} />
          </MathJax.Provider>
        </>
      );
    }
```

At first load, it works fine. But after typing some latex and erasing, it renders the formula twice.

It is not related to strict mode. I tried it already.

Answer (score 1):

There several libraries with the name `react-mathjax`. In this asnwer I'm assuming you're using this one: https://github.com/SamyPesse/react-mathjax

The library wasn't updated for a long time. I recommend switching to a maintained library with support for MathJax v3.

Options:

- [@innodoc/react-mathjax-node](https://github.com/innodoc/react-mathjax-node)
- [mathjax3-react](https://github.com/asnunes/mathjax3-react)

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of react-mathjax-node.

Comment: I have also written a library that supports both versions 2 and 3, feel free to try it out: [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax) :)